# Glassfish 3.1.2 seems not to run more than one thread in an EJB

Tags: asynchronous, glassfish, ejb

I have an EJB to calculate sth. with increasing precision as long as the calculation runs.
So one async function starts the calculation and one async should stop it. But Running on Glassfish 3.1.2 calling `stopCalculating()` does not create a new Thread but waits until `startCalculating()` finishes, what obviously never happens.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ejb.AsyncResult;
import javax.ejb.Asynchronous;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;


@Singleton
public class Calculator {

    private boolean calculating = false;
    private String result = "Empty";

    @Asynchronous
    public void startCalculating() {
        calculating = true;
        Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.INFO, "Starting!");
        calculate();
    }

    private void calculate() {
        result = "";
        while(calculating) {
        /*Calculate and update result*/
            Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.INFO, "Calculate...");
        }
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public Future<String> stopCalculating() {
        Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.INFO, "Stopping!");
        calculating = false;
        return new AsyncResult<String>(result);
    }
}
```

How can I get *Glassfish* to run `stopCalculating()` in an other Thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because by default Singleton EJB has `@Lock(WRITE)` access.

You're using local calls instead of going through EJB proxy so `calculate()` invoked from `startCalculating(-)` is a part of the whole `startCalculating(-)` invocation (so has `@Local(WRITE)` as well).

I'd try adding `@Lock(READ)` to your `calculate()` method and change the local call to business call or just set `@Lock(READ)` for your EJB and give it a shot.